# SQL Solution to Grab Largest Group with Overlap

Tags: sql, group-by, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have an input of a names and associated groups. I desire an output of a de-duplicated version of the input, except for when groups overlap, I want the summation of the overlapping groups.

```
Name    Group
Jeff    1
John    1
Frank   1
Jeff    2
John    2
Frank   2
Fred    2
Steve   3
Sam     3
Jim     3
```

So for this example there are three groups, group 1, 2, and 3. There is overlap between group 1 and 2, (Jeff, John, and Frank all belong to both 1 and 2, and Fred is only in group 2). Given that there's overlap in group 1 and 2, I want to combine them into one single group, with all of the names in either group. I also want to keep groups without overlap separate. This is my desired output:

```
Name    Group
Jeff    1
John    1
Frank   1
Fred    1
Steve   2
Sam     2
Jim     2
```

Is this possible in SQL?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  It would also be handy if you set up a db<>fiddle.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Snowflake is the database.

Comment: What if you had multiple overlaps? Such as PersonA in groups 1,2 and PersonB in groups 2,3 and PersonC in groups 3,4 and PersonD in groups 4,5? Do they all need to go in to the same meta-group?

Comment: @MatBailie this is a great question. Yes, they would ideally all end up belonging to the same group.

Comment: @agdeal - Although I'm convinced SQL is the wrong language/environment to use, I did enjoy ***trying*** to do it in SQL as a theoretical exercise.  I even think it works!  Thanks for the fun puzzle.  ***Note: Don't do this in SQL, even though I gave you an answer ;)***

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution, though it's probably really costly for large data sets.

It's also hard to explain, but I'll try...

---

First, look at how we can combine groups base on "person" alone:

```
PersonA is a member of Groups {1, 2, 3}
   Group2 can therefore be combined in to Group1
   AND
   Group3 can therefore be combined in to Group1

PersonB is a member of Groups    {2, 3, 4}
   Group3 can therefore be combined in to Group2
   AND
   Group4 can therefore be combined in to Group2

PersonC is a member of Groups       {3, 4, 5}
   Group4 can therefore be combined in to Group3
   AND
   Group5 can therefore be combined in to Group3

This gives us...
   From PersonA : (G2 → G1) and (G3 → G1)
   From PersonB :               (G3 → G2) and (G4 → G2)
   From PersonC :                             (G4 → G3) and (G5 → G3)
```

Then look at it "vertically", such that if a group can be combined in to more than one other group, take the lowest option.

```
        Overall : (G2 → G1) and (G3 → G1) and (G4 → G2) and (G5 → G3)
```

If we apply those "combining of groups" to the original data we get this...

```
| person | original groups | revised groups               |
+--------+-----------------+------------------------------+
|   A    | {1, 2, 3}       | {1, 1, 1}       => {1}       |
|   B    |    {2, 3, 4}    |    {1, 1, 2}    => {1, 2}    |
|   C    |       {3, 4, 5} |       {1, 2, 3} => {1, 2, 3} |
```

So, we've gone from 5 distinct groups, to three distinct groups.

If we repeat that process again, starting from the `revised groups`, all three people end up as members of just `Group1`.

The number of times you need to repeat this depends on how many groups overlap each other and in what way.

---

The following code should be able to apply that process as many times as is necessary.  It keeps going until each person is a member of just one group.  There may still be more than one group at the end, they're the groups which ***don't*** overlap with each other.

That may take many iterations, dealing with every person every time, which may be slow, especially on larger datasets.

But, I think, it works for all cases.  *(Even though you probably **shouldn't** do this in SQL, at least now you **can**.)*

***Demo including test data*** : [dbfiddle.uk demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=6f59143a7be76f159e868c9327f8a80e)

```
WITH
  RECURSIVE "membership"
AS
(
  SELECT
    "name",
    "group_id",
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT "name") FROM "name_group_links")   AS unique_names,
    0                                                         AS current_depth,
    COUNT(*) OVER ()                                          AS current_links
  FROM
    "name_group_links"

  UNION ALL

  SELECT
    *,
    COUNT(*) OVER ()   AS "current_links"
  FROM
  (
    SELECT DISTINCT
      "name",
      MIN("min_group_by_name") OVER (PARTITION BY "group_id")   AS "group",
      "unique_names",
      "current_depth" + 1                                       AS "current_depth"
    FROM
    (
      SELECT
        *,
        MIN("group_id") OVER (PARTITION BY "name")  AS "min_group_by_name"
      FROM
        "membership"
      WHERE
        "current_links" > "unique_names"
    )
      AS "collapse_groups_by_name"
  )
    AS "collapse_groups_by_group"
)
SELECT
  "current_depth",
  "name",
  "group_id"
FROM
  "membership"
WHERE
  "current_links" = "unique_names"
ORDER BY
  "current_depth",
  "name",
  "group_id"
;
```

Comment: Attempts at possible optimisation for when number of names is significantly greater than number of groups : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=d5907ae5a1dcfc09ae0a0e3cd6309714